# How to GROUP BY and SUM only if in certain conditions?

Tags: mysql

I need to get SUM of the posted field only if method field has "PART" in it. Here posted is boolean and method is varchar.

Other fields are also selected in this same query so moving the condition to the where clause is not an option.

This is what I have right now, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
# sum of posted
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN method = 'PART%' THEN posted
    END) AS posted_in_background
FROM
    matches_20180905171033
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY method;
```

EDIT: Added GROUP BY and ORDER BY condition to the query

This is the result I'm getting

[image: Result set]

The column has non zero values when I do a normal select

```
SELECT 
    posted
FROM
    matches_20180905171033;
```

[image]

Comment: try `SUM(CASE WHEN method like 'PART%' THEN posted ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: what was the issue in current query

Comment: @JorgeCampos Already tried it, doesn't work

Comment: @BhargavChudasama The result I'm getting is zero

Comment: can you try `upper(method) like '%PART%'`?

Comment: @JaydipRakholiya Thanks man, using like instead of equal fixed it. I might've been blind :p

Comment: @Vizkrig np! You can mark the answer accepted :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes you were right in the first place, I didn't realize I was using `=` instead of `LIKE`. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same issue, using `like` instead of `=` will solve it.

```
# sum of posted
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN method LIKE 'PART%' THEN posted
    END) AS posted_in_background
FROM
    matches_20180905171033
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY method;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN method like 'PART%' THEN posted
    END) AS posted_in_background
FROM
    matches_20180905171033
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY method;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`WHEN method like 'PART%'`

Instead of

`WHEN method = 'PART%'`